# Transferring shares from personal eTrade account to another individual

Tags: online-trading

Is there any feature that eTrade supports that is similar to paypal's sending money to another individual? Instead of sending money I'd hope I can transfer shares to another person's eTrade account for the purposes of bartering. Is this allowed?

Comment: At Fidelity, you must send them a letter telling them to transfer shares from one account to another.  Presumably, eTrade has something similar.  You've got to ask them, though.  (Don't mention barter, trade, etc, though.)

Comment: Check also that even if they can "transfer ownership" without technically selling the shares and re-buying them, it is (a) almost certainly guaranteed that it will count as a disposal by you for capital gains purposes, and (b) very likely they will charge a fee for doing so.